# On the definition of ulp(x) (unit in the last place)

Tags: floating-point, precision, numerical-methods

I have encountered the following definition of the Ulp (from [this](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Carine.Lucas/TPScilab/JMMuller/ulp-toms.pdf) article<sup>1</sup>, Definition 5.):

[image]

Despite something left unclear (does the word *linearly* in the definition mean that between two FP (floating point) numbers this function is linear -- not a constant) as I understand the *ulp distance* between two real numbers is proportional to the number of FPs between these numbers. However, judging from the next usage of that definition (in that article) it just makes no sense:

[image]

here *x* is a real number, *X* is a FP number, RN(*x*) means that *x* is rounded to the nearest FP number. The quantities on the sides of the above inequality are of different nature: LHS is a real number (which can be arbitrary small) and RHS is discrete (number of FP numbers between *x* and *X*).

## Update

Suppose the precision is 0.1. The FPs are 0, 0.1, 0.2, ... Take *x*=0.06 and *X*=0.3. Then *I(x)*=0.6, *I(X)*=3 and we have |*x-X*| = 0.24, and ulp distance is 2.4 so the inequality is fullfilled but the conclusion that *x* is rounded to the nearest FP isn't true.

Am I missing something?

---

1. On the definition of ulp(x), Jean-Michel Muller

Comment: Note this is attempting to define a unit-in-the last-place function of a real number  `x` 
 (something without a "last place") and not only of a floating-point encoded value (something with a "last place").

Comment: Re Update: That does look off; |x-X| is a distance in original units of real numbers, while ½δ(x, X) is a distance in units of ULP. Maybe a typo or missing scale factor? I will look at it further when I have some time.

Comment: @Eric, absolutely agree. That is why I'm saying of different nature of those quantities in my post.

Comment: I looked at the paper again, and I still think that is a mistake. Maybe it should be δ_ulp(x, X) < ½?

Answer (score 5):

### Initial Question

The definition means that, given two consecutive floating-point numbers, *X* and *Y*, for which I(*X*) is *q* and I(Y) is *q*+1, then for any real number *z* between *X* and *Y*, I(*z*) = *q* + (*z*-*X*)/(*Y*-*X*). That is, as *z* goes from *X* to *Y*, I(*z*) goes from *q* to *q*+1, and it does so linearly: I(*z*)-I(*X*) is proportional to *z*-*X*. For example, if *z* is located at one-third or one-half of the way from *X* to *Y*, then I(*z*) is q+⅓ or q+½.

This means I is piecewise linear: Within any interval where the exponent of floating-point numbers does not change, I is linear. But it changes where the floating-point numbers move to a new exponent.

> … as I understand the ulp distance between two real numbers is proportional to the number of FPs between these numbers.

This will not be true when spanning intervals where the exponents change, because the slope of I varies.

Also, even within an exponent interval, it only approximates the number of floating-point numbers between two points. For example, if only integers were representable, we might have I(4.25) = 4.25, I(3.75) = 3.75, so I(4.25)−I(3.75) = .5, but there is one floating-point number (4) between them. At the same time, I(3.25) = 3.25, so I(3.75)−I(3.25) = .5, but there are no floating-point numbers between them.

> The quantities on the sides of the above inequality are of different nature: LHS is a real number (which can be arbitrary small) and RHS is discrete (number of FP numbers between *x* and *X*).

The right-hand side is a continuous real function, as shown above.

### Update

The statement |*x* − *X*| < ½δ<sub>*ulp*</sub>(*x*, *X*) ⇒ *X* = RN(*x*) appears to be an error, as |*x* − *X*| is a unitless real-number distance, whereas δ<sub>*ulp*</sub>(*x*, *X*) is in units of ULPs. Perhaps this should have been δ<sub>*ulp*</sub>(*x*, *X*) < ½ ⇒ *X* = RN(*x*)? It appears to have been added at the suggestion of a reviewer for the paper and may not have received as much scrutiny in other parts. For further reading, I recommend [*Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic* by Muller *et al*](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/Handbook.html).